# How can I monitor the progress of a package removal or install via python apt?

Tags: 14.04, apt, python

For example let's say I want to remove chromium-browser in ubuntu via my script below. How can I monitor the progress of the removal?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# aptremove.py

import apt
import apt_pkg
import sys

def remove():
    pkg_name = "chromium-browser"
    cache = apt.cache.Cache()
    cache.open(None)
    pkg = cache[pkg_name]
    cache.update()
    pkg.mark_delete(True, purge=True)
    resolver = apt.cache.ProblemResolver(cache)

    if pkg.is_installed is False:
        print (pkg_name + " not installed so not removed")
    else:
        for pkg in cache.get_changes():
            if pkg.mark_delete:
                print pkg_name + " is installed and will be removed"
                print " %d package(s) will be removed" % cache.delete_count
                resolver.remove(pkg)
    try:
        cache.commit()
        cache.close()
    except Exception, arg:
        print >> sys.stderr, "Sorry, package removal failed [{err}]".format(err=str(arg))

remove()
```

Comment: My initial thought is that, no, there's no universal solution for monitoring the progress of such a script; you would have to write the code to monitor the progress yourself. However, I don't know if there is some sort of specific way to do this with apt.

Comment: What if it's multiple packages? I updated my script a bit, I I have a list of packages to remove, after each remove I'll be able to see some progress. But would there be a better way to do it besides mine?

Comment: Something like https://www.apt-browse.org/browse/ubuntu/trusty/main/all/python-apt-doc/0.9.3.5/file/usr/share/doc/python-apt/examples/progress.py?

Comment: @muru thanks! I can see that this could help me a lot